# How to use distutils or setuptools in setup.py to make a cython extention importable (without needing to append to sys.path before every import)?

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, setup.py, cythonize

I have cython extention which I install in the following way:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize(
    "package.pyx",
    language="c++")
)
```

When I want to import this package, I need to append the build folder to path using:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(~/package/build/....)
```

What needs to be changed in the installation to have the module install into Linux and be importable without having to append to path?

I am also open to using setuptools.

Comment: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try my `setup.py` as a template... these things aren't exactly well documented. One thing to remember here is if you build `inplace` you probably will have to `from projectname.module import module`:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension

module = 'MyModuleName' # this assumes your .pyx and your import module have the same names
# ignore the below extra options if you don't need them (i.e. comment out `#`)
ext_modules = [Extension(module, sources=[module + ".pyx"],
              include_dirs=[],
              library_dirs=[], 
              extra_compile_args=[],
              language='c++')]

setup(
    name = module,
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = [np.get_include(), os.path.join(np.get_include(), 'numpy')]
    )
```